# Units of $\mathbb Z[\zeta_8]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory, diophantine-equations

> Let $R=\mathbb Z[\zeta_8]$. I conjectured that $R^\times$, which is the units of $R$, as a set, is $\{\sigma^n\zeta_8^m\mid n,m\in\mathbb Z\}$, where $\sigma=1+\sqrt2$. Hence, I can get $R^\times\cong\mathbb Z\times C_8$. Can we prove it?

Suppose $x=a+b\zeta_8+c\zeta_8^2+d\zeta_8^3$. Noticing the proof of $R$ being euclidean, or taking the denominator of $x^{-1}$, we get a norm $$N:R\to\mathbb N, x\mapsto (a^2+c^2)^2+(b^2+d^2)^2+4(ab+cd)(ad-bc).$$ As it can be verified that $N$ preserves multiplication, the question boils down to finding the integer solution of $$(a^2+c^2)^2+(b^2+d^2)^2+4(ab+cd)(ad-bc)=1.$$
I'm not sure how to continue. Considering $\operatorname{im} N$ being non-negative, I believe that there is a way to complete the square or quartic power. I tried factorization but I cannot get a quartic factorization.

---

On the other hand, if I'm given $R^\times\cong\mathbb Z\times C_8$, by noting that $\sigma=1+\sqrt2$ is a unit, and that the multiplicative subgroup generated by $\sigma$ and $\zeta_8$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z\times C_8$, we just need to verify all real units to find all units. This can be easily done by solving a Pell equation.

Comment: Note that $K=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_8)\supset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, and $1+\sqrt{2}$ is a fundamental unit of the quadratic field, so a fundamental unit of $K$ is $(1+\sqrt{2})^{1/n}$. But when $n>1$, it is not in $K$, so $n$ must be $1$.

Comment: A variety of expressions for the norm is given in [Math.SE 2929371](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2929371/). Some of those are more useful for this type of exercise than others.